# Error al crear una vista parcial fuertemente tipada en Visual Studio Express con el motor Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, vistas

Cuando se intento crear una **vista parcial fuertemente tipada** en visual studio 2012, recibo el siguiente error (En inglés):

> There was a problem getting an AppDomain to run the transformation from the host. The process cannot continue.

Este problema no se presenta al crear vistas que no sean parciales.

**¿Qué estará pasando?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias soluciones a este problema:

1. **Reiniciar Visual Studio** (El principio número uno de la informática)
2. **Actualizar la versión del Administrador de Paquetes Nuget** (Desde el menú herramientas)
3. Si nada de lo anterior funciona, habrá que **reparar la instalación de Visual Studio** (Es el caso más drástico).